# Please suggest an idiom

Tags: idioms

Can you please suggest an idiom meaning the same as ' to take advantage of ' in the context that a group of people attacked another one that was already in civil war.

Comment: You can greatly improve this question by editing to provide a handful of additional details.  In what context will this idiom be used?  Who exactly are the two groups of people?  Right now, I could think of dozens of example that *might* fit or might not, depending on these details.  Hit 'em when they're down, rub salt in their wounds, take candy from a baby....

Comment: "Inserted themselves into a domestic dispute"? "Seized the opportunity created by the civil war"? "Opportunistic attacks"? We need more examples of how you would use the phrase in actual sentences in order to help you.

Comment: "To fish in troubled waters": to take advantage of a confused situation. For example, He often buys up stock in companies declaring bankruptcy; fishing in troubled waters generally pays off. (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fish+in+troubled+waters)

Answer (score 2):

> suggest an idiom meaning the same as ' to take advantage of ' in the context that a group of people attacked another one that was already in civil war

- ***kick them while they are down*** means to take advantage of a temporary weakness to inflict damage.
- ***pile on*** means to join an attack already under way.